# Springboot não renderiza imagem (apenas se reiniciar)

Tags: java, spring-boot, processamento-de-imagens

Tenho uma entidade chamada produto que tem apenas Título, Preco e caminhoImagem, esta última guarda o caminho em que a imagem do produto está salva. Ao receber esses dados do formulário o meu service executa este código:

```
public void addProduto(Produto produto, MultipartFile imagem) {
    String caminho = "/img/" + produto.getTitulo().replaceAll(" ", "") + ".jpg";
    produto.caminhoImagem = caminho;
    UsingFileUtils.salvarImagem(caminho, imagem);

    repo.save(produto);
}
```

Removo todos os espaços do título e mando para a classe UsingFileUtils que faz isso:

```
public static void salvarImagem(String caminho, MultipartFile imagem) {
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/static"+caminho);
    try {
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file,imagem.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Ao fazer isso, é redirecionado para a página com todos os produtos, mas a imagem não é renderizada, apenas se eu reiniciar o servidor, aí aparece normalmente. No html de listagem está assim:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" th:each="produto : ${produtos}">
                <img class="card-img-top" th:src="@{${produto.caminhoImagem}}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${produto.titulo}"></h5>
                    <p class="card-text" th:text="${produto.preco}"></p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Quero</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

O que posso fazer pra não ter que reiniciar o servidor pra renderizar as imagens?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que, segundo [este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41351474/4319922) *post*, a pasta `static` é carregada apenas na inicialização da aplicação pelo Spring Boot, qualquer alteração no conteúdo desta pasta só vai ser refletida na próxima inicialização do servidor.

Isso posto, possíveis soluções:

1) Colocar suas imagens em outra pasta que sensibilize o Tomcat a restartar automaticamente e, via Maven, copiá-las para a pasta `static` original. Esta solução está [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764196/4319922).

2) Usar o [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/), que automatiza esse processo de guarda e recuperação de recursos estáticos no ambiente Spring. Dê uma lida [neste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50663879/4319922) post.